# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT' (In stored procedure EXEC)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running my stored procedure that takes only one argument of type `DATE`. The name of the argument is *DateParam*

```
EXEC [MyDBNAME].[dbo].[SPName] @DateParam = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

But I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

I have seen this error in many other questions here as well as other forums. But I did not find one that answers the problem. Thanks for looking!

Comment: You can't use expressions here.  Assign the value to a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't parse expressions in `exec`.  So assign to a parameter:

```
DECLARE @today DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());

EXEC [MyDBNAME].[dbo].[SPName] @DateParam = @today;
```

I imagine that Microsoft has a good reason for this limitation -- such as parsing ambiguities in the line.  It is a pain.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! But we should add "AS DATE" in the `Declare` line. `DELCARE @today AS DATE`.

Comment: Will accept as answer in 5 mins ;)